# Perl fails to kill self pid when running from bash script

Tags: perl, terminal, signals, kill-process

Following code behaves as expected when running **from terminal**:

```
perl -e 'kill -2, $$; warn HERE, $/'
```

It sends itself `SIGINT` and dies before reaching "HERE":

```
~# perl -e 'kill -2, $$; warn HERE, $/'

~# echo $?
130
~#
```

The problem: same code fails to kill self PID when running **from shell script**:

```
~# cat 1.sh
perl -e 'kill -2, $$; warn HERE, $/'
~#
~# sh 1.sh
HERE
~#
~# echo $?
0
~#
```

On the other hand, replacing perl's `kill` by a shell's one works OK:

```
~# cat 2.sh
perl -e 'qx/kill -2 $$/; warn HERE, $/'
~#
~# sh 2.sh
~#
~# echo $?
130
~#
```

Not really understand what is happening here, please help..

Comment: By the way, `kill INT => -$$` is a nicer way of writing `kill -2, $$`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all,

```
 kill -2, $$
```

is better written as

```
 kill 2, -$$
```

An even better alternative is

```
 kill INT => -$$
```

These send `SIGINT` to the specified process group.

---

Your main question appears to be why the two shells behave differently. This section explains that.

The process group represents an application.

When you launch a program from an interactive shell, it's not part of a larger application, so the shell creates a new process group for the program.

However, processes created by a script (i.e. a non-interactive shell) are part of the same application as the script itself, so the shell doesn't create a new process group for them.

You can visualize this using the following:

- `sh -i <<< 'perl -e '\''system ps => -o => "pid,ppid,pgrp,comm"'\'''` outputs the following:

  ```
  $ perl -e 'system ps => -o => "pid,ppid,pgrp,comm"'
    PID  PPID  PGRP COMMAND
   8179  8171  8179 bash
  14654  8179 14654 sh
  14655 14654 14655 perl
  14656 14655 14655 ps

  $ exit
  ```

  In interactive mode, `perl` is at the head of `perl` and `ps`'s program group.
- `sh <<< 'perl -e '\''system ps => -o => "pid,ppid,pgrp,comm"'\'''` outputs the following:

  ```
    PID  PPID  PGRP COMMAND
   8179  8171  8179 bash
  14584  8179 14584 sh
  14585 14584 14584 perl
  14586 14585 14584 ps
  ```

  In non-interactive mode, `sh` is at the head of `perl` and `ps`'s program group.

---

Your failures are the result of not sending the signal to the head of the process group (i.e. the application). Had you checked, the error `kill` reported was `ESRCH` ("No such process").

> `ESRCH` The pid or process group does not exist. [...]

To kill the current process's process group, replace the improper

```
kill INT => -$$           # XXX
```

with

```
kill INT => -getpgrp()    # Kill the application
```

---

You can make your `perl` the head of its own process group by simply calling the following:

```
setpgrp();
```

Test:

```
$ sh <<< 'perl -e '\''system ps => ( -o => "pid,ppid,pgrp,comm" )'\'''
  PID  PPID  PGRP COMMAND
 8179  8171  8179 bash
16325  8179 16325 sh
16326 16325 16325 perl
16327 16326 16325 ps

$ sh <<< 'perl -e '\''setpgrp(); system ps => ( -o => "pid,ppid,pgrp,comm" )'\'''
  PID  PPID  PGRP COMMAND
 8179  8171  8179 bash
16349  8179 16349 sh
16350 16349 16350 perl
16351 16350 16350 ps
```

That's not something you normally want to do.

---

Finally, the Perl code

```
kill INT => -$pgrp
```

is equivalent to the following call of the `kill` command-line utility:

```
kill -s INT -$pgrp
kill -INT -$pgrp
kill -2 -$pgrp
```

You were missing `-` in your `qx//` program, so it was sending SIGINT to the identified process rather than the identified program group.

Comment: I'm disappointed you picked the "answer" that doesn't even answer your question (why the two shells behave differently).

Comment: Sorry to hear you're disappointed, didn't mean to.. Both explanations look pretty equal for me, seriously. Am I wrong? Why do you think the picked one doesn't answer my question?

Comment: Both explanations? I only see one. Both of our answers explain why how process group works, but that's not what you asked why the two shells behave differently, and they other answer doesn't explain that at all. Only mine answers that (the concept of applications). Did I miss something? /// In fact, the other answer claims the two shells could behave identically (by saying the process group creation by the non-interactive shell is only *likely*), but that's wrong!

Comment: I think a _likely_ word in another answer refers to **non-existent process group**, and doesn't mean **probably a new pr group is created**. IMHO the sentence just says perl sends `SIGTERM` to foreign (and probably non-existent) pr group..

Comment: Likely does indeed refer to non-existent. If it's likely it's non-existent, that means it's likely it didn't get created, which means there's a possibility it could get created, but that's completely wrong. Non-interactive shells don't create the process group, and as I explained, the reason for that is because the shell sees `perl` as part of the same application.

Comment: _which means there's a possibility it could get created_ - RIGHT, it could already exist as ANOTHER application, that's the meaning of a sentence.

Comment: No, the process group `$$` can't possibly be created by a non-interactive shell. The process doesn't exist before the shell creates it, so the only way `$$` can be a process group is if the shell makes it one. It's not just likely that it's not a process group, it's guaranteed. The non-interactive shell will *always* behave differently than the interactive shell (for the reasons I explained); it's not just likely. ("[The process group `$$`] could already exist as ANOTHER application" makes no sense.)

Comment: Oops, now I understand) Thanks for extra explanation. You probably should add that as comment to 'another' answer.

Answer (score 4):

From your **interactive terminal**, the perl process kills the process group of which it is a part.  (The shell runs perl in its own process group.)  The shell reports this unusual termination in `$?`:

```
t0   interactive shell (pid=123, pgrp=123)
       |
t1     +------> perl -e (pid=456, pgrp=456, parent=123)
       |          |
t2   (wait)      kill(-2, 456) (in perl, same as kill pgrp 456 w/ SIGINT)
       |          |
t3   (wait)     *SIGINT*
       |
t4   report $?
```

From your **shell script**, the perl process kills a (likely) non-existent process group and then exits successfully.  Your interactive shell makes a new process group in which to run your shell script, and that script then runs perl as a child in the same process group.

```
t0   shell (pid=123, pgrp=123)
       |
t1     +-------> shell:1.sh (pid=456, pgrp=456, parent=123)
       |          |
t2   (wait)       +-------------> perl -e (pid=789, pgrp=456, parent=456)
       |          |                |
t3   (wait)     (wait)            kill pgrp 789 with SIGINT (error: no such pgrp)
       |          |                |
t4   (wait)     (wait)            exit success
       |          |
t5   (wait)     exit success
       |
t6   report $?
```

In your **backticked (`qx//`) example**, your interactive shell starts a shell process with a new process group.  (Not that it matters here, but that process runs perl in its same process group.)  Perl then runs as its own child the system `kill` command, *the semantics of which differ from that of the perl `kill`*.  This grandchild command sends a SIGINT to the perl PID directly, rather than a SIGINT to a process group.  Perl terminates, and that exit code is conveyed as the script's exit code, since it was the last command in the script.

This diagram is a little busier than the previous:

```
t0   shell (pid=123, pgrp=123)
       |
t1     +-------> shell:2.sh (pid=456, pgrp=456, parent=123)
       |          |
t2   (wait)       +----------> perl -e (pid=789, pgrp=456, parent=456)
       |          |             |
t3   (wait)     (wait)          +---------> /bin/kill SIGINT 789
       |          |             |             |
t4   (wait)     (wait)         *SIGINT*      exit success
       |          |
t5   (wait)     return $?
       |
t6   report $?
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine in this way:

`perl -E 'say "kill "INT", $$; warn HERE, $/'`

`perl -E 'say "kill 2, $$; warn HERE, $/'`

[kill](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/kill.html) man page says:

> A negative signal name is the same as a negative signal number,
>   killing process groups instead of processes. For example, kill
>   '-KILL', $pgrp and kill -9, $pgrp will send SIGKILL to the entire
>   process group specified. That means you usually want to use positive
>   not negative signals.

Comment: Thank for answer, but this still doesn't explain difference between `kill -2, $$` and `qx/kill -2 $$/`

Comment: pretty sure this'll be down to how `$$` is being expanded.

Comment: `qx/kill -2 $$/` calls OS kill cmd, but `kill -2, $$` is pure perl code.

Comment: sure, but why killing process group by perl `kill` doesn't work as OS kill?